# First matter-transmitter story where the philosophical aspects of it are discussed?

Tags: history-of, teleportation

Characters discuss (there may be more than one answer, like first destructive copy, etc.) :

1. If a known destructive copy, how anyone would voluntarily use it?
2. They question whether it is a destructive copy
3. If the matter of your feet (for example) is transformed into the matter of your brain, is it really the original person?
4. Questions about consciousness/soul really being transported
5. Characters sent whether they want to be sent or not
6. Concerns about problems reconstructing -- The Fly may not have anyone worried about the reconstruction, but it is problems like that or simply that the transported individual may no longer be as healthy (introduces genetic error)

EDIT: To limit it to one answer, I guess it is the first "philosophical objection" (or even practical like genetic defects being introduced) to using a matter-transmitter, any of the things or some other concern I did not list.

EDIT: It may be that the first non-magic teleportation is the amazingly prescient (he came up with amazing ideas so early) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edward_Page_Mitchell story The Man Without a Body. Written in 1877 there is a technical problem, and this was 80 years or so before The Fly.

Since this is said to be in the Wikipedia article on Teleportation the first use of the term "matter-transmitter" and discusses converting a cat into telegraph signals (yes, 2 years before Einstein was born, matter into energy, sort of although perhaps more like a fax machine conceptually) and when he uses it himself his body is missing, I would be surprised if anyone comes up with something earlier.

Although: Even if the means of transmission is magic, a problem caused by using this magic, resulting in a human missing part of himself or some other undesirable result would be of interest.

Comment: Much too late for a "first" but I seem to recall that the "philosophical aspects" of teleportation came up in Ray Brown's [*Reformed Sufi*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?40480) series.

Comment: @user14111 it's good to have a starting point for the search

Comment: There's a *lot* of this in the very early (1970) Star Trek tie-in novel *Spock Must Die* by Blish. Some in the earlier (1960) *Rogue Moon* by Budrys. But these are probably too late to be firsts as well.

Comment: The earliest teleportation mishap yarn I know of is "An Extra Man" (1930) about an experimental matter transmitter which accidentally creates two copies of the passenger. Probably not "philosophical" enough for you.

Comment: There is an old story (which I can't ID offhand) where a woman dies in an accident, and a backup copy is made (with some missing memory of course) from the last time she traveled by transmat. The "philosophical discussion" (if you can call it that) is that her husband is creeped out and considers her a kind of zombie, until the same thing happens to him.

Comment: I think you need to limit this to a single answer, opening it up to "more than one answer" gives this a reason to be closed.

Comment: @user14111: Interesting plot twist with the husband/wife. 1930 sounds pretty old even for a teleportation (by non-magic) and the two copies is of course one of the core issues.

Comment: @Skooba-Stands-Against-AI: I do not want to limit it to a specific sort of concern especially because in the same story, multiple opinions/concerns might be expressed.

Comment: Something similar at least (making copies, although not for transport) is discussed in Lem's Dialogues from 1957: https://english.lem.pl/works/essays/dialogs/106-a-look-inside-dialogs. As the name suggests, this is explicitly a philosophical work.